# How to adress a label thats made in codebehind from Tick event of dispatchtimer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, label, code-behind

I have a label that is generated in the Loaded event of stackpanels that are added in codebehind to a grid. My question is how do i adress the labels from the Tick function ?

I thought about selecting a label with xpath like this: XPATH=//label[1] 
Or adding a name as in the example below

And id really like to keep labels in xaml out of the solution

```
private int GridRow = 2;
private int GridColumn = 2;

            public GameWindow()
            {

            InitializeComponent();

            Grid TheGrid = GameGridOfficial;

            for(var rij = 0; rij < 5; rij++)
            {
                GridColumn = 2;

                for(var kolom = 0; kolom < 2; kolom++)
                {
                    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                    sp.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, GridRow);
                    sp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, GridColumn);
                    sp.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
                    sp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);

                    sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    sp.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    sp.Loaded += Sp_Loaded;
                    TheGrid.Children.Add(sp);                    
                    GridColumn += 2;
                }
                GridRow += 2;
            }

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();

        }

        private void Sp_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
        if (sender is StackPanel)
            sp = (StackPanel)sender;

        Label labelTimer = new Label();
        labelTimer.Width = GridOfficial.ColumnDefinitions[3].ActualWidth / 2;
        labelTimer.Height = GridOfficial.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight;
        labelTimer.Content = "00:00:00";
        labelTimer.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Impact");
        labelTimer.FontSize = 32;
        labelTimer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
        labelTimer.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        labelTimer.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        labelTimer.Name = "labelTickTimer";

        sp.Children.Add(labelTimer);

        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelTickTimer.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
```

its the labelTickTimer that can't be found obviously.

Hope information and code is sufficient for you guys. I've been quite the lone ranger lately, constantly googling while i continue my .NET & C# programming course in school.

Greetings

Comment: declare `Label labelTimer` in class scope (along with `GridRow`) and refer to it by variable name, not by assigned name (`labelTimer` vs. "labelTickTimer"). Or look it up by name in the `Controls` tree.

Comment: Thanks alot ! Your first solution worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private int GridRow = 2;
private int GridColumn = 2;
Label labelTimer=null;

        public GameWindow()
        {

        InitializeComponent();

        Grid TheGrid = GameGridOfficial;

        for(var rij = 0; rij < 5; rij++)
        {
            GridColumn = 2;

            for(var kolom = 0; kolom < 2; kolom++)
            {
                StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
                sp.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, GridRow);
                sp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, GridColumn);
                sp.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
                sp.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 2);

                sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                sp.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                sp.Loaded += Sp_Loaded;
                TheGrid.Children.Add(sp);                    
                GridColumn += 2;
            }
            GridRow += 2;
        }

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();

    }

    private void Sp_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    if (sender is StackPanel)
        sp = (StackPanel)sender;

    labelTimer = new Label();
    labelTimer.Width = GridOfficial.ColumnDefinitions[3].ActualWidth / 2;
    labelTimer.Height = GridOfficial.RowDefinitions[2].ActualHeight;
    labelTimer.Content = "00:00:00";
    labelTimer.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Impact");
    labelTimer.FontSize = 32;
    labelTimer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aquamarine);
    labelTimer.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    labelTimer.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
    labelTimer.Name = "labelTickTimer";

    sp.Children.Add(labelTimer);

    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelTimer.Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
```